Jest/Vitest React testing library unable to trigger a custom load event - Cannot set property which only has a getter
I am attempting to fire a load event where the target property in the load event is customised.
test:
 const onLoad: ImageSrcSetProps['onLoad'] = (e, options) => void vi.fn(e, options);
 // pass the mock to the component to ensure it's called correctly when the image loads
 renderWithProviders(<ImageSrcSet {...getProps({ onLoad })} />);
 // crux of issue:
 const image = screen.getByRole('img'); 
 fireEvent.load(image, { target: { currentSrc: 'foo' } }); // you can't do this.

component
  const handleOnLoad = useCallback(
    (e: React.MouseEvent<HTMLImageElement>) => {
      console.log('currentSrc!!!--->', e.target.currentSrc, '<----');
    },
    [onLoad]
  );
  ...
 <img
   srcSet={getImageSrcSet}
   src={placeholderGif}
   role="img"
   onLoad={handleOnLoad}
 />

( The currentSrc is the image that the browser loaded - it varies based on screen size )
I have tried:
Object.defineProperty(global.Image.prototype, 'currentSrc', {
  writable: true,
});

But this will break vitest ( and probably jest too )
Error: Uncaught [Error: cannot spy on a non-function value] which is caused by mock `onLoad`


So yeah, catch-22 and stuck. Suggestions?
Update 30-05-2024
Changes/Corrections made.

Use currentTarget rather than target.currentSrc
No need to mess with global.Image.prototype

Current issue - can't seem to fireEvent(image, myEvent) in order for the onLoad to be asserted.
Minimal reproduction:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/rtl-template-4m1vc8?file=src%2FApp.test.tsx
